# Multiple images to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I would like to upload multiple images to firebase. Currently I can upload 1 image. Although, I have decided to place all the content as HTML, such as title, description and images into a single webview and display it from there. At the moment this work fine, and I have a string containing all this in firebase:

```
Hi<br>first image<br>
<img src=\"content://media/external/images/media/45972\">
<br>hi<br>second image<br>
<img src=\"content://media/external/images/media/45841\"><br>"
```

Although, as you can see this is only working form local storage. How would download these images and replace the image src with the correct firebase image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your best options:

1. [Download the image to a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_to_a_local_file) and display that.
2. [Get the download URL for the image](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) and display that.

If you want a simpler all-in-one solution, consider [using the FirebaseUI wrapper for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui).

Comment: Will it get all the images from the HTML and download them at once?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You will need to write code to interact with Cloud Storage through its Firebase SDK. The links I gave show how to do that.